# Invalid /bin/bash address while implementing return-to-libc

Tags: c, security, gdb

I'm trying to implement return-to-libc explotation according to [this](http://lasithh.wordpress.com/2013/06/23/how-to-carry-out-a-return-to-libc-attack/) tutorial. Everything seems to work perfectly, but I cant get the correct address of $BINSH. It seems like the variable is stored at 0xffffecbb, but gdb says that it cant access the address. Where can be the mistake? The address of system() is 0x7ffff7a5a530 and exit() 0x7ffff7a50180 and both of them are accessible via gdb.

Comment: $binsh is not a function, it is something that should be executed by system.

Comment: Yes, its a parameter passed to system()

Comment: What address does getenv(BINSH) show?

Comment: 0xffffecbb

However,it seems like $BINSH is located in different locations every time I run retlib. Hence, how can I check where it is located at to implement the vulnerability?